Global search parameters that works on any and almost every APPLICATIONS
Good day all,
I have a platform where we manage users 2FA tokens, we search and manage users one after the other.
However, we need to manage multiple users at once but there is no delimeter, concatenate rule that works when we combine multiple user ID's to search.
Please note that if I leave the search box empty and click enter, it populates all the users (10k+ users) all at once with paginations.
But I need a standard, Global search code, or master search code to crack this, so i can search not all but specific users and perform certain tasks on them simultaneously.
